# Error 403 Image not found in Drupal 7

Tags: php, image, drupal-7, localhost, http-status-code-403

I create a block from configuration. Inside this block, I write this code...

```
 <div class="provider-bg" id="provider1">
      <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_path().path_to_theme() ?>/images/provider-1.jpg" />
 </div>
```

Then, I save with **PHP** in text format.

My virtual host is ... http://localhost:8888/drupal 
So, the image path will be like this ...

```
<img alt="" src="/drupal/sites/all/themes/myancast/images/ios.png">
```

This image appears in the last few days ago. Today, I run the site and that image disappear immediately and got 403 error.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)**. 
I'm trying to find the solution the whole day. But, I still cannot solve. 
Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Provide full url of image and check image exists or not

Comment: http://localhost:8888/drupal/sites/all/themes/myancast/images/ios.png .. this is the full image path bro. The image exist bro. I got this error. You don't have permission to access /drupal/sites/all/themes/myancast/images/ios.png on this server. I change chmod 777 to images folder and all the images inside in it bro. But, not work :(

Answer (score 2):

Add global $base_url in your code and use like below

```
<img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $base_url.'/'.path_to_theme(); ?>/images/provider-1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try this ?

```
<img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo '/'.path_to_theme(); ?>/images/provider-1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```html
<?php
 $imgurl = file_create_url(path_to_theme().'/images/provider-1.jpg');
?>
<img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $imgurl ?>"/>
```